Trying to find projection of PNG image of Central Asia
I have the following map: 
I am trying to figure out what projection this is in. I tried many but nothing lines up... I also tried the georeferencer in QGIS but the results are very lacking.
How could I do this?

What was this issue with georefencer in QGIS?  Did it place it in the correct spot on the earth?

I used it many times but the results are just never right. I used different sets of GCP's... Also different types of transformation types: Linear and Projective. Projective results were much better

Your map may not be to scale.  Did you try Freehand Raster Georeferencer?  That will allow you to scale and stretch the map to known points.

Hi I also tried that unfortunately it really doesnt align.

Which did you try? How about EPSG:32642 (UTM 42N)?

GRID-Arendal created the maps in 2016 contact them https://www.grida.no/about#staff they have GIS/Cartography staff
